# Ubuntu Desktop for Raspberry Pi: brcmfmac enable power save take too long and stop the next screen from ever loading

Tags: raspberrypi

```
brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled
```

is exactly what shown on screen and on `journalctl`

SSH daemon is up and running so troubleshooting is more possible (because Ubuntu Desktop for Raspberry Pi doesn't use grub so switching to recovery mode is hard)

Answer (score 0):

This [Solution](https://forum.clockworkpi.com/t/how-to-disable-wifi-power-save-to-prevent-disconnects/933) found usable. It's important not just create the script but update `chmod` permissions.